# Validate multiple field types on a form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am trying to run through both input and select field types to validate form inputs and am stuck

Originally was using getElementsByTagName by read that the querySelectorAll might do the trick. It is still functioning with the input fields, but not the select ones. y = x[currentTab].querySelectorAll('input','select') Is there a way to get both input and select fields from my form included in this?

```js
function validateForm() {
  // This function deals with validation of the form fields
  var x, y, i, valid = true;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  y = x[currentTab].querySelectorAll('input','select');
  // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    // If a field is empty...
    if (y[i].value == "") {
      // add an "invalid" class to the field:
      y[i].className += "invalid";
      // and set the current valid status to false
      valid = false;
    }
  }
  // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
  if (valid) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
  }
  return valid; // return the valid status
}
```

Comment: `y[i].value == ""` is not correct in `Java`. Do use `y[i].value.isEmpty()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `querySelectorAll` takes only one parameter, you can't get both `<input>` elements and `<select>` ones at the same time.

So you change the validation loop into the function, and then pass each type of the elements you get by `querySelectorAll` to it.

**Edit:** Also, for select boxes you have to check their `selectedIndex` instead of just `value` property.

```js
// A function that checks all elements are valid (not empty)
function validateElements(elements) {
  let valid = true;
  for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    const e = elements[i];
    
    // Check if the value is empty for the input fields
    // and the index is zero for the select boxes
    if ((e.tagName.toLowerCase() === "input" && e.value == "") ||
      (e.tagName.toLowerCase() === "select" && e.selectedIndex === 0))
      if (elements[i].value == "") {
        // add an "invalid" class to the field:
        elements[i].className += "invalid";
        // and set the current valid status to false
        valid = false;
      }
  }
  return valid;
}

function validateForm() {
  // This function deals with validation of the form fields
  var x, y, i, valid = true;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  inputs = x[currentTab].querySelectorAll('input');
  selects = x[currentTab].querySelectorAll('select');

  const validInputs = validateElements(inputs)
  const validSelects = validateElements(selects)
  valid = validInputs && validSelects
  // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
  if (valid) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
  }
  return valid; // return the valid status
}
```

Comment: Thank you but it seems i am missing something here - 
https://jsfiddle.net/MBRAZITI23/a72b6uph/5/. If the "select" element is working it should turn red when i click the next button as it would be marked invalid and false.

Comment: @mbraziti23 I added validation for select boxes into my post. For `<select>` you must check not `.value` but `.selectedIndex` (or `.options[index]`) You must also define css for the invalid select box in your jsfiddle example.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help i added in your code and updated the css : select.invalid { background-color: #ffdddd ; } but it is still not turning to that color: https://jsfiddle.net/MBRAZITI23/a72b6uph/26/ i took out the standing option in the field so that it is 100% blank

Comment: I'm sorry, I added `validInputs` & `validSelects` in validateForm function. Everything is now fine.

Comment: And if you set the value of the default option in the select box to empty string, you can use `<select>.value` property as I originally wrote.

Comment: This is incredible. Thank you!!